# AngularJS how to sum data from database in the view

Tags: mysql, angularjs, database, html-table

I have a table, with one column for each day of the week, in which with a ng-repeat, I put the hours worked on a specific project in that week.

The data gets pulled from a database.
What I'm having trouble with is, each project can have different subprojects, and when this happens, they all get put in a rowspan under the same main project, as you can see in the image ( the "SU" Project has 2 subprojects "ghfgh" and "testtesttest").

[image: example image]

Now, the total hours in the last column gets pulled as well from the database, where all the hours of a project in a specific week are summed.
How can I make that IF a project has subprojects, their hours that week get summed in a single rowspan as well? (in the image I put an arrow showing the result wanted)

If I use the same code to give the rowspan to the subprojects, it gives the right rowspan to the total column, but obviously only shows the hours of the first subproject (in this case "ghfgh")

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in vm.presences">
                <td ng-if="p.showProject" rowspan="{{p.projectCount}}">{{p.projectName}}</td>
                <td>{{p.description}}</td>
                <td>{{p.monday}}</td>
                <td>{{p.tuesday}}</td>
                <td>{{p.wednesday}}</td>
                <td>{{p.thursday}}</td>
                <td>{{p.friday}}</td>
                <td>{{p.saturday}}</td>
                <td>{{p.sunday}}</td>
                <td ng-if="p.showProject" rowspan="{{p.projectCount}}">{{p.total}}</td>
            </tr>
```

and the code used to check if there are multiple entries of the same project in a given week, to group them in the same rowspan is

```
weeklyPresences.forEach((p, i) => {
                        const differentProject = i === 0 || weeklyPresences[i - 1].projectName !== p.projectName;

                        p.showProject = differentProject;

                        if (differentProject) {
                            p.projectCount = weeklyPresences.filter(pres => pres.projectName === p.projectName).length; 
                        } else {
                            p.projectCount = weeklyPresences[i - 1].projectCount;
                        }                        
                    });

                    return weeklyPresences;
```

any idea on how I could group the hours of the subprojects?

I was thinking about some loop that checks if a project has multiple entries like the code above, if it doesn't, the var total stays the same, otherwise, it takes them and sums them in a new var.

Comment: you can use reduce method

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr= [1, 2, 3];
var sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(sum); // 6
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'm pretty new to angular, could you explain me what happens here:  

var sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

Comment: this is the method for getting sum of array elements.where value of a and b changes according to index starting with 0th index.you can use this method with object also.let say you have person object with name and age parameter and you want sum of ages.

Comment: var person = {{name:"gaurav", age:25},{name:"Amit",age:20},{name:"rahul",age:26}}

var sum = person.reduce(function(a,b){
return a+b;
},0)

Comment: so in my case, my array has other numbers, but I only wanna sum the ''total'' values of entries of the same project! 
I can see the reduce function working for an array where you just wanna sum everything inside it, but I need first to check if there are multiple entries with the same project name, and sum only them!